# Creating a custom Solr core in docker using docker

Tags: solr, docker

I am trying to create a custom solr index using custom schema with docker container approach. I am able to create a custom index, but I am not able to associate it with the custom schema.

I did copy a json file with the names of the custom indexes to the c:/data folder of solr-init container in solr-init DockerFile as a part of creating a custom index, although I ma not sure how can I map the custom schema with this core.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "containery" way to do this is to create your own `solr-init` image based off of the Sitecore one and copy in your own configset with the custom schema and create the core as part of the script. The container itself provides several scripts to help with this, e.g., `New-SolrConfig.ps1`, `New-SolrCore.ps1`, `Patch-SolrConfig.ps1`, etc.

You can create your own script to run the default `Start.ps1` and then perform whatever custom work you need to do, then use your custom script as the entrypoint for your container.